# How to make an action when the page fails to load?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I know when a page fails to load?
When there's a server error, and I get the gray window that sayd "Google Chrome fails to load this page..." or "this page in  not available" ?

I want to add my extension an option of auto refresh after 10 seconds. I work with some web-app that sometimes the server fails to load for some reason, and a refresh just brings it back to life.
So I'm looking for auto-refresh in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the `chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function details){}` listener. Per the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html), errors that are triggered by any event before the completion of a request will fire the `onErrorOccurred` method. The `details` will contain information about the error, but in your case it sounds like any triggered error should cause a refresh, so perhaps something like this (completely untested, more theoretical :) ):

```
chrome.webRequest.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function details){
    chrome.tabs.reload(details.tabId);
}
```